# arange horizontal line of buttons in Pyside/PyQT/Qt

Tags: qt, button, layout, pyqt, pyside

I want to create a simple GUI with PySide/PyQt. 
In this GUI I want to have a raw with severeal push buttons and the length of the  buttons I want to be proportional to its text label. 
Looking at QPushButton and QHBoxLayout I don't see a posibility this can be done easy.

Any advice in this respect?
Thanks
Dimitar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do with Tool Buttons. In Qt Designer:

- Create the tool buttons and set the text
- Put them in a horizontal layout
- Add a horizontal spacer to the beginning and/or the end of the layout

Optionally, you could also:

- Set a minimum width/height
- Change the size-policy of the buttons to minimum/minimum

Comment: QSizePolicy.Minimum  The sizeHint() is minimal, and sufficient. The widget can be expanded, but there is no advantage to it being larger. It cannot be smaller than the size provided by sizeHint() . 
In your first step do you mean setting the buttons sizeHint to the size the text label can fit? Do you mean I have to use something like QFontMetrics here?
For the second step. I don't see why you say minimum twice? 
What will hapen if for the current button font the total amout of the label text is bigger than the window who store my raw with buttons? It will scale the buttons proportionaly ?

Comment: @DimitarPenev. I can tell from your questions that you are not using Qt Designer, which makes it so easy to experiment with this sort of thing. If you use Tool Buttons, rather than Push Buttons, there is no need to bother with size hints or calculating the width. Tool Buttons will automatically resize themselves to fit the text. Try it! The other things I mentioned are just suggestions for fine-tuning, and are entirely optional (`minimum/minimum` refers to the horizontal and vertical size policy). Use Qt Designer!

Comment: I have tested both pushbutton and toolbutton in Qt Designer and they have similar behaviour. Fortunately they both reflect their size as per the test label they show. Qt Designer indeed look as very usefull tool. Thanks ekhumoro